# Ember.js setup controller and then accesing model within the controller

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'm new to Ember.js, this is my first app which has a notifications area, always visible.  As this notification area is included in the application template and there is no specific route for it, I added the number using the {{render}} Helper and setting the model from the ApplicationRoute:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    ...
    {{#link-to "notifications"}}
        {{ render "notification-totals" }}
    {{/link-to}}

    <div class="dropdown">
       {{outlet notifications}}
    </div>
    ...

</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notification-totals">
    {{this.firstObject.total}}
</script>
```

The ApplicationRoute sets the model to the controller:

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
        this.controllerFor('notification-totals').set('model',this.store.find('notification.total'));
    }
});
```

The Model:

```
App.NotificationTotal = DS.Model.extend({
    total: DS.attr('number')
});
```

How can I access the model within the Controller? Nothing I try seems to work, for example:

```
App.NotificationTotalsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    total: function() {
       var model = this.get('model');
       .....
    }.property()
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code should work fine. You should be getting an array of your model objects, because that's what the route is setting as model.

For example:

```html
  <script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <div><h3>Notifications:</h3>
    {{ render "notification-totals" }}</div>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="notification-totals">
    {{total}}
  </script>
```

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function() {
      var data = [
        {
          total: 7
        }, {
          total: 8
        }, {
          total: 12
        }
      ];
      this.controllerFor('notification-totals').set('model', data);
    }
});

App.NotificationTotalsController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    total: function() {
      var model = this.get('model');
      return model
        .mapBy("total")
        .reduce(function (prev, cur) {
          return prev + cur;
        }, 0);
      console.log(model);
    }.property("model.@each.total")
});
```

This controller will access all the model objects and generate the sum (`{{this.firstObject.total}}` will get you totals only from the first object). Working demo [here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/nugurume/2/edit).

If you're still getting nothing, check if your data source is getting anything (this demo uses hardcoded values instead of ember data).

Comment: This works! The data source was getting the data but I was missing the property("model.@each.total") in the controller. Anyway, the total is actually a single value {"notificationTotals":[{"total":85}]}, that's why I was using {{this.firstObject.total}}. Is there a way to indicate the model it has a single value and access with property("model.total") ? Thanks!!!!!

Comment: The best solution would be to change this: `this.store.find('notification.total')` to return just one object (I'm not into ember-data, so I can't help you there). Alternatively, you can attach .then to the promise ember-data returns. Something like this: `.find(/*...*/).then(function (arr) { return arr[0]; })`